# Stuck on Apple logo after attempted iOS 8.0.2 update

Tags: ios, ipad

My iPad was at the latest iOS 7.x when I decided to update it to 8.0.2 via iTunes.  At the end of the update I got an error, 6 IIRC.
After that the iPad was stuck in restore mode for around half an hour.  When it got out of restore mode somehow (without doing a restore) it wouldn't boot up.  It gets as far as the Apple logo then dies after a few seconds.  It does the same thing whether plugging into a laptop or a wall charger.

To make things worse the sleep/wake button is stuck.

How can I unbrick this thing?

Edit:  I've found that by pressing the home button while plugging into the laptop, I can put it in restore mode again.  But restoring is a last resort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I had to get the iPad to a useable state so I went ahead with the restore.

This was a non-ideal solution, I'll be checking back to see if anyone has other upvoteable ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Try holding the top (lock/unlock) button and Home button together for a few seconds. It worked for me.

Comment: The question states that the button is stuck.

Answer (score -1):

RECOVERY MODE

1. Turn off iPad
2. Turn on computer and launch iTunes (make sure you have the latest version of

iTune)

3. Plug USB cable into computer's USB port
4. Hold Home button down and plug the other end of cable into docking port.

DO NOT RELEASE BUTTON until you see picture of iTunes and plug

5. Release Home button.

ON COMPUTER

6. iTunes has detected iPad in recovery mode. You must restore this iPad before it

can be used with iTunes.

7. Select "Restore iPad"...

Note:

1. Data will be lost if you do not have backup
2. You must follow step 1 to step 4 VERY CLOSELY.
3. Repeat the process if necessary.

Comment: While helpful as a set of instructions of how to restore, this doesn't actually answer the question.